# How to postgresql select one table and json

Tags: postgresql

My postgresql version is 14.9
there is test_table

| Name (Txt) | content (JSONB) | additional (JSONB) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ao | [{ "no": "5", "op": "66" }, { "no": "5", "op": "88" }] | [{ "op": "88" , "dep": "3"},{ "op": "66" , "dep": "9" }] |
| bo | [{ "no": "5", "op": "22" }, { "no": "3", "op": "33" }] | [{ "op": "22" , "dep": "2" },{ "op": "77" , "dep": "7" }] |
| co | [{ "no": "5", "op": "99" }, { "no": "5", "op": "11" }] | [{ "op": "11" , "dep": "1" }] |

I want this select sql output.

| Name (Txt) | content (JSONB) | additional (JSONB) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ao | { "no": "5", "op": "66" } | { "op": "66" , "dep": "9" } |
| ao | { "no": "5", "op": "88" } | { "op": "88" , "dep": "3" } |
| bo | { "no": "5", "op": "22" } | { "op": "22" , "dep": "2" } |
| co | { "no": "5", "op": "99" } |  |
| co | { "no": "5", "op": "11" } | { "op": "11" , "dep": "1" } |

I want add additional (JSONB) filtering
additional("op") = content("op")
and Name (Txt) and content (JSONB)
by content("no")
like over table result.

I did try this sql.

```
SELECT
   "Name (Txt)",
    jsonb_build_object('no', elem->>'no', 'op', elem->>'op')  AS "content (JSONB) "
FROM test_table,
     jsonb_array_elements("content (JSONB)") AS elem
WHERE elem->>'no' = '5';
```

this is result.
but I don't know add additional like over result table.

```
| Name (Txt) | content (JSONB)                | 
|----------- |--------------------------------| 
| ao         | { "no": "5", "op": "66" }      | 
| ao         | { "no": "5", "op": "88" }      | 
| bo         | { "no": "5", "op": "22" }      | 
| co         | { "no": "5", "op": "99" }      |                         
| co         | { "no": "5", "op": "11" }      |
```

Comment: what happens if the number of JSON elements in content is not the same as in additional?

Comment: @S-Man
    if  value of "op" is not same , add empty .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another `jsonb_array_elements()` to get what you want.

Also, use the ANSI join syntax with `lateral`:

```
select t.name, c.content, a.additional
  from test_table t
       cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.content) c (content)
       left join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.additional) a (additional)
         on a.additional->'op' = c.content->'op'
        and c.content->>'no' = '5';
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_nbEi99g)

Comment: cross join can't select like that result

Comment: @booompal  Look at the linked fiddle.  Does it match your results?  That is a lateral cross join.